# Getting all games with the same category as a chosen game

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm developing an online game website, what I want to achieve is, while I'm playing 
a game I want to show in the same page all the games related to the category of the game played at the moment. For example: I'm playing the game which id = 4 and the category of that game is = 3. I want to show all the games related to the category 3. And so on. Thank you

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jogos` (
`idGames` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`strNome` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`intCategoria` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

 $varCategoria_GameData = "0";
 if (isset($_GET["cat"])) {
 $varCategoria_GameData = $_GET["cat"];
 }
 mysql_select_db($database_gameconnection, $gameconnection);
 $query_GameData = sprintf("SELECT * FROM jogos WHERE jogos.intCategoria = %s",     GetSQLValueString($varCategoria_GameData, "int"));
 $GameData = mysql_query($query_GameData, $gameconnection) or die(mysql_error());
 $row_GameData = mysql_fetch_assoc($GameData);
  $totalRows_GameData = mysql_num_rows($GameData);
   if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
 session_start();
 }?>
```

Comment: can you add the SQL statement that you tried?

Comment: Hi, go-oleg, just added

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: I changed the title to something more descriptive. Feel free to correct it. This is mainly an SQL question.

Comment: James Poulson, no problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this ?

```
SELECT * FROM jogos WHERE intCategoria =
( SELECT intCategoria FROM jogos WHERE idGames = $currentGameId )
```

Where `$currentGameId` is the id of the game being played.

Comment: How can I adapt this to my sql? I'm sorry, I'm new at php

Comment: This would be the SQL query from within PHP. If possible, get the id of the current game, cast it to int and save it to $currentGameId. The value will be injected into the string if the query text is between quotes (").